# "why angular 5 is running on ( http://127.0.0.1:5500/src/index.html) and nothing is been displayed on browser"

Tags: angular

"I have started my project using angular/cli which was running fine on localhost 127.0.0.1:4200, but after some days i restart my it was running on localhost:127.0.0.1:5500 and nothing is been display after i run live server on my vs code."

"I have tried to manually changed the port from 5500 to 4200 default but unfortunately it's not working"

Comment: did you try with ng serve -o it will automatically run with your 4200 port

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to run live server from Vscode. If you run

```
ng serve -o
```

or

```
ng serve --open
```

it will automatically run in your default browser with your default port 4200

Comment: thanks man it's working after I start my project using "ng -start"